# How to use grid-template-areas in react inline style?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

So, I've been playing with `css-grids` in react when I noticed that `grid-template-areas` has a bit different syntax which might not be compatible in inline react styles. I'm not using any libraries just plain old react inline styles with style prop.

So what I'm aiming to do is similar to this.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "aside main"
                       "footer footer"
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid green;
} 

.aside {
  grid-area: aside
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

*Fidde: https://jsbin.com/lejaduj/2/edit?html,css,output*

The layout is simple, "header" and "footer" covering all the columns and "aside" and "main" covering the half. This is just for demo purpose so I kept it simple.
Notice particularly how `grid-template-areas` has multiple values separated just by double quotes.

After some thought I thought we could use arrays in `gridTemplateAreas` in react inline styles. That didn't seem to work.

I again tried with [`template-literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which didn't work either.

*Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zx4nokmr5l*

So, is it just me that's hitting this obstacle or is this not supported yet in react?

I'd rather not use any extra library or framework in react to achieve this as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to use `grid-template-areas` with the HTML `style` attribute (i.e., CSS inline styles), then use single instead of double quotes.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  /* grid-template-areas: "header header"
                          "aside main"
                          "footer footer"; */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrapper" style="grid-template-areas: 'header header' 'aside main' 'footer footer' ">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="aside">aside</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Part of your question addressed the double quotes. That's the issue I addressed.

Comment: Holy shit. You might have inadvertently helped me. Of course you can add single quote inside a double quote even in `json`. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks for the help. If you can edit your answer to reflect that then I'd be happy to mark this correct.

Comment: LOL. I was thinking in terms of PHP, which is where I normally use this method.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want me to edit the answer. Feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: Edited. Feel free to add more if there are anything that needs to be added.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for React, where `class` should be `className`, kebab-case should be camelCase, styles should be objects, etc. Chris Wingler's answer below is much more correct for a React application.

Answer (score 63):

Just use backtick strings.

```
gridTemplateAreas: `
                    'header header'
                    'aside main'
                    'footer footer'
                   `
```

For inline style in JSX:

```
<div
  style={{ gridTemplateAreas: `'header header' 'aside main' 'footer footer'` }}
></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

if you need an object in style, this works

```
    myStyle = {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateAreas: "'header' 'content' 'footer'",
        gridTemplateRows: '50px calc(100vh - 100px) 50px' 
    };
```

and use the style object inline

like I did using styletron

```
    import { styled } from 'styletron-react';

    const myStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke',
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateAreas: "'header' 'content' 'footer'",
        gridTemplateRows: '50px calc(100vh - 100px) 50px'
    };

    const Layout = styled('div', (props) => (myStyle));

    export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who have a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
let grid2D = [
 ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3"],
 ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3"],
 ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"],
 [".","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"],
 [".","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"]
]
```

to concatenate the array so it fits into an inline style, you can use this one liner

```
let stringGrid = "'" + grid2D.map(arr => arr.join(' ')).join("' '") + "'";
```

In a react component it can work like this:

```
export class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grid2D: [
       ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3"],
       ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3","area-e06e944f-a50a-4630-ac19-6c85ca0e7bc3"],
       ["area-70774248-ed4a-4f60-8341-46d4173344f8","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"],
       [".","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"],
       [".","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410","area-1d20d72e-5383-47aa-bcc4-8aaed8137410"]
      ]
    };
  }

  getTemplateAreas(grid2D) { 
    return "'" + grid2D.map(arr => arr.join(' ')).join("' '") + "'"; 
  }

  render() {
    const { grid2D } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ gridTemplateAreas: this.getTemplateAreas(grid2D), display: 'grid', width: '100%', height: "100%" }}>
         {grid2D.map((arr, i1) => {
          return arr.map((id, i2) => {
            return <div key={i1 + '' + i2} style={{ gridArea: id }} />;
          });
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> Important: grid-area names/ids have to start with a alphabetic character